# UILocalNotification Object in DidFinishLaunching always nil?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

I am creating a **local notification** for a specified date as follows

```
UILocalNotification *localNotify = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
        [localNotify setFireDate:notificationDate];
        [localNotify setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];
        [localNotify setAlertBody:@"Daily Items Reminder"];
        //[localNotify setAlertLaunchImage:@"blank_Btn"];
        [localNotify setAlertAction:@"View"];
        [localNotify setSoundName:UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName];
        [localNotify setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
        [localNotify setRepeatInterval:NSDayCalendarUnit];
        NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"dict"
                                                             forKey:@"key"];
        localNotify.userInfo = userDict;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotify];
        [localNotify release];
```

In my **ApplicationDidFinishLaunching** i create an object for **UILocalNotification** as follows

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent];

UILocalNotification *notification = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];

if (notification)
{
    NSInteger badgeNumber =  notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber;

    if (badgeNumber < 0)
    {
        notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = badgeNumber - 1;
    }

    [self showAlertMessage:@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" withButtons:eOk forDelegate:self];
    // open screen
}
}
```

After clicking on View Button when **Local Notification** appears the application starts, now **launchOption** should return the **localnotification object** thru the key but the it always returns nil as the alertview is not getting called??.. what am i possibly doing wrong??

Comment: i don't understand your question ., can you please be more specific ??

Comment: the notification object i made in applicationDidFinishingLaunching always returns Nil